# Dynamic and static linking in iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

i'm trying to use static libs (.a) in my project. I've added "lib*.a" in "frameworks" and added liker flags "-ObjC".  lib*.a are compiled for i386 to be run in iOS simulator. Though the app was build without error it can't be launched in iOS simulator because of error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/asmirnov/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/D87A3FA9-7207-40B4-9EA0-5F06CEF6EF7B/StaticLibraryUsage.app/StaticLibraryUsage
  Reason: image not found
```

Why .dylib file is required even if i try to use static linking? Will using .dylib prevent the app from being distributed in AppStore?

Comment: You must be linking against the `.dylib` and not the `.a` file.  You can check this using `otool -L <executable>`.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but i'd like to understand and not just "do that way". Can you please answer the questions above?

Comment: The issue is that you are using `-L` and `-l` linker options, which will find the `.dylib` file and link against them instead of the `.a` file which is (probably) in the same directory.  In order to force the link against the `.a` file it's necessary to drop the `-L` and `-l` options and simply add the path to the the `.a` file in *Additional Linker Flags*: `/path/to/file/libclang.a`.

Comment: Why .dylib file is required even if i try to use static linking (with .a files)?